# How to compute the multiplicity of a strongly convex, rational, polyhedral cone $ \sigma $?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, toric-varieties

In David Cox, John Little and Hal Schenck's book **Toric Varieties** page 302, Chapter 6, Section 4, Proposition 6.4.4, the authors state the following proposition.  If $ \Sigma $ is a simplicial fan of in $ N_{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n} $, $ \sigma = \operatorname{Cone}(u_{\rho_{1}},\dots,u_{\rho_{n}}) $, $ \sigma^{'} = \operatorname{Cone}(u_{\rho_{2}},\dots,u_{\rho_{n+1}}) $ are two cones of $ \Sigma(n) $, $ \tau = \operatorname{Cone}(u_{\rho_{2}},\dots,u_{\rho_{n}}) $ is a cone of $ \Sigma(n-1) $ and if $ \alpha u_{\rho_{1}}+\sum_{i=2}^{n} b_{i} u_{\rho_{i}}+\beta u_{\rho_{n+1}} =0 $ is a wall relation, then $ D_{\rho} \cdot V(\tau) =0 $ for $ \rho \notin \{\rho_{1},\dots,\rho_{n+1}\} $, $ D_{\rho_{1}} \cdot V(\tau) = \operatorname{mult}(\tau)/\operatorname{mult}(\sigma) $, $ D_{\rho_{n+1}} \cdot V(\tau) = \operatorname{mult}(\tau)/\operatorname{mult}(\sigma^{'}) $ and
\begin{align*}
D_{\rho_{i}} \cdot V(\tau) &= \frac{b_{i} \operatorname{mult}(\tau)}{\alpha \operatorname{mult}(\sigma)} \\
&= \frac{b_{i} \operatorname{mult}(\tau)}{\beta \operatorname{mult}(\sigma^{'})}.
\end{align*}
The multiplicity of a simplicial cone $ \gamma = \operatorname{Cone}(u_{\rho_{1}},\dots,u_{\rho_{k}}) $ is the index of the sub-lattice $ \mathbb{Z}u_{\rho_{1}}+\cdots+\mathbb{Z}u_{\rho_{k}} $ in $ \left(\mathbb{R}u_{\rho_{1}}+\cdots+\mathbb{R}u_{\rho_{k}}\right) \cap N $.  This quantity looks fairly cryptic, and in Example 6.4.5, the authors simply write out what the multiplicities of the cones are without much explanation.

Is $ \operatorname{mult}(\gamma) $ the same quantity as the measure of the $ k $-dimensional parallelepiped with vertices $ u_{\rho_{1}},\dots,u_{\rho_{k}} $?  This looks very much like what is described as the multiplicity of $ \gamma $ and in Example 6.4.5, the authors seem to have calculated this quantity without explanation.  However, I wanted to be certain.

Comment: Yes, should be the same as (appropriately normalized) volume of parallelepiped; it is also the gcd of the maximal minors of the matrix whose columns are the vectors.

Comment: Thank you @SamHopkins.  Do you have a reference for these facts?

Comment: This is not the best reference, but you'll see what is going on if you look at Theorem 2.2 of Stanley's 1991 paper "A zonotope associated with graphical degree sequences" (https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/83.pdf)